# How do i store GMT offset with the DATETIME in MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, offset, gmt, datetimeoffset

I was using C# with MS SQL Server 2008

Now i want to migrate to MySQL server
5.5

> **But i dont know how to store the `GMT offset` value in what data type
>   of the MySQL Server?**
>
> Please help me store C#'s datatype
>   `DateTimeOffset` to `MySQL server`

Anybody please help me?

Thanks,
Chintan

Answer (score 1):

It has to be stored as a separate field.  In MySQL, and most databases, date+time is a stored as a single scalar value, a 32- or 64-bit integer, depending on the specific time datatype.

Either store it as the corresponding entry in `mysql.timezone.Time_zone_id`, or use your own timezone table.